# Add two times the same class on one element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

lately I am doing some refactoring on a legacy project for my work and I stumbled upon something "buggy" probably.

Somewhere within the framework a custom pageloader reads the `controller/action` from an endpoint and applies those as two classes on the body.

It does lets say something like so:

```
$('body').removeAttr("class").addClass(controller + ' ' + action);
```

With `index` as controller and `cars` as action the body would look like:

```
$('body').removeAttr("class").addClass('index cars');
<body class="index cars">
```

So far so good (not quite).

Later again to match the specific element you would do:

```
$('.index.cars')
```

Now there is a problem if the action and the controller have the same name. 
The two classes are applied, lets say `cars/cars` would look like so:

```
<body class="cars cars">
```

The selector `$('.index.cars')` works fine with the above.

Now the interesting part is that if you try to add the class with jQuery 1.11.1 then this doesn't work. It can't add a second class with the same name on one element.

So this:

```
$('body').removeAttr("class").addClass('cars cars');
<body class="cars">
```

does not work :-(

Searched a bit at google and here but could not find something.

The question is:

Is it valid to have 2 times the same class on one element? If yes, then are there any specific reasons someone would do so apart from creating a selector with classes?

Comment: Why don't you add a validation before `addClass(controller + ' ' + action);` to check if names are same before you append them.

Comment: Thanks @emmanuel . I know ways to solve this, but I was just wandering...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050851/use-duplicate-class-name-on-an-element

Comment: Great thanks @LcSalazar (feeling a bit stupid atm) :-) . So probably a jQuery thing... I marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid to have multiple duplicate classes for an element. Check out the Moz Developer reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/class

Basically, whatever is calling it will recognize both instances for the same element, but will treat it as one class.

To answer your second question as to a reason for someone to utilize this…I personally can't think of one?

As to your problem above, you are removing the attribute 'class' on your element, then adding it back with class values. For example: `<div class="car">` becomes `<div>`, then it becomes `<div class="controller action">`

You could just use `.removeClass` to replace `.removeAttr`

See here: http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

Hope that helps? Good Luck!